# A Login Page using PDO prepared statements not working but otherwise working fine

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**PHP Code for login using pdo and prepared statements but not working**

but not working it always enters `if numr_rows<=0` case

```
session_start(); // Starting Session
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
      $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
   }
   else
   {
      // Define $username and $password
      $username=$_POST['username'];
      $password=$_POST['password'];
      $stmt = DB::getInstance()->prepare("select * from tour_login where password=':password' AND username=':username'");
      $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
      $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
      $stmt->execute();

      $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();    
      $num_rows = count($rows); 

      if($num_rows<=0)
      {
         echo "<script>alert('No country Exist');
         document.location='addcountry.php';</script>";
         return false;  
      }
      else
      {             
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {                               
           //echo "Entered successfull for loop"; 
           if($row['type']==0)
           {    
              $_SESSION['admn']=$username;
              echo "<script>alert('welcome admin...');
              document.location='home.php';</script>";
            }
            else
            {
              $_SESSION['usr']=$username;
              echo "<script>alert('welcome user...');';</script>";
            }                           
          }
        }
      }
```

** If prepared statements is commented out and uses this it works fine **

```
$result=DB::getInstance()->query("select * from tour_login where password='$password' AND username='$username'");
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
$num_rows = count($rows);

    if($num_rows<=0)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('No country Exist');
        document.location='addcountry.php';</script>";
        return false;   
    }
    else
    {                   
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            //echo "Entered successfull for loop"; 
            if($row['type']==0)
            {
                $_SESSION['admn']=$username;
                echo "<script>alert('welcome admin...');
                document.location='home.php';</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['usr']=$username;
                echo "<script>alert('welcome user...');';</script>";
            }
          }
        }           
      }
```

What is that I am doing wrong with prepared statements ?.New to php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bind like this:

```
  $stmt = DB::getInstance()->prepare('SELECT ... WHERE password = :password AND username = :username');
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
  $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

*No quotes* around your parameters. It's simply `:password`, not `':password'`. Binding does not work like interpolating values into strings. The placeholders are actual placeholders for *values*, the database will figure out itself whether these are strings or numbers or whatever.

Comment: Is there something else wrong with my code ? Is it the right way ?